# React Native cannot find Android Studio or SDK

Tags: android, linux, react-native

OS: Ubuntu

Running `npx react-native doctor` yields:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWm0i.png)

As you can see react native does not recognise the existence of android studio or sdk.

I have configured my environment variables to the following:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/opt/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Exact path of Android studio:

```
/opt/android-studio-ide/android-studio/bin
```

Exact path of Android Sdk:

```
/opt/Android/Sdk
```

Android studios is installed and working, and by extension so is the sdk. I have followed the instructions on how to setup react and ensured all the correct packages have been added. See here:

Snippets from Android Studio

[SDK Platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxowH.png)

[SDK Tools 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Kv6.png)
[SDK Tools 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQXkB.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake I made was putting the `$HOME` variable in `export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/opt/Android/Sdk` making the path `/home/opt/Android/Sdk`